# Migrate from Exchange 2007 to OpenChange/Zentyal

Tags: migration, zentyal

Hi we're trying to run a test migration from Exchange 2007/SBS 2008 to Zentyal 3.5.. so far we've managed to get across our AD users/groups without too much hassle.

Where we're falling down is getting mailboxes over for our users -- this is an absolute requirement for us due to regulatory constraints.

There is a built-in tool (a technology preview feature), that you can access via a "/Migration/" URL on the server. Whilst this does claim it has connected, it then reports no mailboxes were found.

I've seen other possibilities for extracting the emails alone via imapsync but this would leave out Calendar entries.

We've also (successfully) extracted someones mail into .PST and then imported it back into Outlook on the new server. This, is fairly impractical given the ~70 users we have though.

Is anyone aware of another approach to this we could take to get our old mail/calenders out of Exchange?

Answer (score 1):

I would first contact Zentyal's support.  They should be able to assist.  I don't know this product, but if it doesn't have hooks into Exchange then the only real possibilities are PST exports (either manually or via the `Export-Mailbox` cmdlet).

You can look at the `Export-Mailbox` cmdlet below.  It's easy enough to run and you can create a PS script if you like to loop through each mailbox or a set of mailboxes (based on `-Identity`) that you are currently migrating if you are doing it over time.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266964%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx